# Python 3.5 bytes-like object is required

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

I have a code section using pyserial to get output from an external device. No matter how I decode the `readline()` output it throws an error. I test each condition first, but when used in a `while`  it errors.

```
mess = ser.readline().decode().strip("\r\n")
print(mess)
print(mess != "")
print("Off" not in mess)
print(mess is not None)
while mess != "" and "Off" not in mess:
    if "Google" in mess:
        #code
```

gets me a response of:

```
On
True
True
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 57, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 38, in main
    while mess != "" and "Off" not in mess:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Not sure what to do to fix this

Comment: Move your debugging `print`s into the while, it seems the error was not raised in first iteration of the loop.

Comment: Are you modifying `mess` in the `while` loop? It seems so, otherwise its an infinite loop. Check what you assign to `mess`.

Comment: My crystal ball says that you have another `ser.readline()` in the `while` loop, but you don't `decode` the result.

Comment: Well, @tdelaney, your crystal ball was correct. I forgot to add the decode to the second `readline`, I saw it fail on the `while` and assumed it never got past that.

Comment: While loop conditionals can be hard to debug. Debuggers let you inspect the variables for each iteration which can be helpful.

Comment: If someone makes an answer I can pick it.

Answer (score 0):

@tdelaney had a comment which lead to my solution:

> My crystal ball says that you have another ser.readline() in the while
>   loop, but you don't decode the result.